# Image background on Both sides (left and right)?

Tags: html, css, background

I have a hard time to get  background on both side of my page:

**Style**

```
.left {
   background: url(wax.png);
   width: 15%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}
.right {
   background: url(wax.png);
   width: 15%;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}

.middle{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="left">

</div>

<div class="middle">
</div>

<div class="right">

</div>
```

**Result**

[image]

Its close to what I am trying to achieve but the right image is misplaced.

Also the backgrund is not repeated vertically

Answer (score 0):

```
 background: url(wax.png) repeat-y 0 0;
```

To get the vert repeat.

Do you have something positioned relative? That input text field is probably pushing down the right div unless you have something else positioned relative?

If you're going to use position:absolute, wrap it all and use position:relative on that wrapping div.

Otherwise, you could use the body tag or even the html tag but it's probably better to use a wrapping container.

Comment: It's a table in a div, please check my HTML `<div class="middle">`

Comment: As you're just getting started, one thing you don't want to get into the habit of is using tables for layout. You don't need. A table is a block element meaning, it will automatically take up it's own space rather than being 'inline' such as a span, em, or strong tag.

Comment: Yes I know table is bad for layout, as you can see I have the middle div that wraps it, I added the table when I couldnt get it to work, it does not work with the div either please advice

Answer (score 0):

im not really sure what you are trying to do it looks align to me but for repeating image is this background: url(wax.png); background-repeat: no-repeat

Comment: look the tight image its shifted down

Comment: try to add background image in middle class see what happens or change the color

Answer (score 0):

> Its close to what I am trying to achieve but the right image is
>   misplaced.

Add `top:0` to the .right class

> Also the backgrund is not repeated vertically

As others have mentioned add repeat-y in the background property value

`background: url(wax.png) repeat-y`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want to place your middle inside one div with the background repeated in both direction and middle having background white

html:

```
<div id="background">
  <div id="content">
    this was middle
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#content{
  margin: 15%;
  background: white;
}

#background {
  background: url(wax.png);
}
```